# How to use the `\p{Assigned}` regexp selector?

Tags: ruby, regex

I just read about the `\p{Assigned}` selector in the Ruby Regex documentation, which sounds like a good possibility to easily generate an array of characters that it is supposed to match? The only thing it says in the documentation though is 'An assigned character'.

How do I assign one/multiple characters to this selector?

Comment: I'm not sure how to use `\p{Assigned}`, it raises an exception here: `invalid character property name {Assigned}: /\p{Assigned}/`. However, if you just want a regex to match one of a set of characters, e.g., one of 'a', 'b', 'c', just create your own character class: `/[abc]/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Unicode assigned characters](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/#assigned_character) are the whole of graphic, format, control, and [private-use](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/#private_use_code_point) characters, i.e. any character that is not [reserved for future assignment](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/#reserved_code_point). You can't assign arbitrary characters to the class `\p{Assigned}`.

Answer (score 1):

See https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/3838
You need to specify that the encoding is UTF-8 by adding 'u' after the expression

```
/\p{Assigned}/u
```

Comment: That indeed seems to solve all `\p{ ... }` related errors thrown when trying to use them. Good to know. It throws the error in `irb`, though not when running a script file. I suppose `irb` is not running in utf-8.